# Connecting PHP Script to Java with Socket

Tags: java, php, sockets

I am trying to host a webserver with a little php script which sends **one** line to a java programm (on local machine) and gets **one** line back from the Programm. After that another client should be able to connect. I am currently getting some timeouts by the php script and can't figure out why...

**Java**

```
public void start() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true) {
                Socket client = serversocket.accept();

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));


                String[] request = in.readLine().split(";");
                String answer = "";

                ...getting the answer...

                out.println(answer + "\n");
                out.close();
                in.close();
                client.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen(getHostByName(getHostName()), 77777, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "test\n");
    echo fgets($fp, 128); 
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: My guess is a stream buffer is holding on the output on one side or the other. I would try flushing after each write operation. Maybe after the `fwrite` in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i had a permanentloop in the "getting the Answer" part. Now it works fine.
Anyway, here is my new PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Cannot create a socket");
    socket_connect($sock,getHostByName(getHostName()),7777);
    $data = "arg1;arg2;arg3\n";
    socket_write($sock, $data, strlen($data));
    echo socket_read($sock, 2048);
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

And make sure to add/uncomment this in your php.ini file:

*extension=sockets*